# Is there any way to detect text wrapping in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to detect text wrapping in a textarea?

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve? If you don't want text wrapping then use a `input type='text'` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do like this it might work

http://www.jsfiddle.net/rKysm/

here is an updated version where it will fit your selector

Comment: This would work it the textarea had attribute wrap and it wasn't set.  The only attribute of this textarea is id.

Comment: @Babijer i've updated the code that should work for all cases